# Append figure and/or text to existing pdf in a new page (python)

Tags: matplotlib, pdf, pdfpages

I want to call a function that plots data in a pandas dataframe and appends the plot to an existing pdf file.

```
def plot_and_pdf(df,pdf_file):
   f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1,figsize=(15,8),sharex=True)
   pp = PdfPages(pdf_file)
   ax1.plot(df['col1'])
   ax2.plot(df['col2'])
   pp.savefig()
   pp.close()
```

The problem is that this overwrites the file, it does not append the figure to a new page.

The function gets called every time a given event takes place in the main program. I know that I may tweak the code in such a way that I create a 2nd pdf file and merge the two pdfs each time such an event happens, using pyPdf as in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118510/append-page-to-existing-pdf-file-using-python-and-matplotlib), then deleting the excess pdf.

I'm looking for a more 'direct' way, without the workaround and merging, if it exists. As `PdfPages` is basically a wrapper around `PdfFile`, maybe there is a way from there but I couldn't figure it out from the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.html#PdfPages).

Comment: It is assumed that the pdf is written to the start of the file. Tools like pyPdf are more likely helpful here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So your advice is to go for merge/delete each time?